# Of two boxes rasterized by tcolorbox, the left one is cut short

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

The following compiles under cleveref v0.19 and tcolorbox v3.80 with TeXLive 2013 under osx 10.6.8 but the left box is cut short.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk  

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins, raster} 

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
number within=chapter]{EXAMPLE}[1][]{% 
breakable,
enhanced,
grow to left by=5mm,
grow to right by=5mm,
detach title,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
fontupper=\small\sffamily,
colframe=white,
colback=white,
coltitle=black,
title={EXAM},
#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Some text to show the margins. Some text to show the margins. Some text to show the margins.  

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]
\begin{EXAMPLE}[unbreakable]{Some Title}
tcolorbox requires for a box to be rasterized that it be unbreakable. 
\end{EXAMPLE}
\begin{EXAMPLE}[unbreakable]{Some Title}
This is my own box.
\end{EXAMPLE}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot check right now, but cleveref is not used here

Comment: Correct. I normally do have cleveref for cref and cpageref. Took it out of the code but not of the message. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with `grow to left by` and `grow to right by`. These options change `bounding box` compared with needed box and boxes overlaps when placed with a `raster`.

Next figure shows how both boxes are placed with a `raster` but declared without `grow to` option:

[image]

Now with your original design:

[image]

Dotted red line is obtained with `show bounding box` option, while the red line is `tcolorbox` frame. As you can see, `bounding` boxes are correctly placed but because `tcolorboxes` are not transparent (`colback=white`) and used boxes are larger than their bounds, right box covers part of left one.

A possible solution would be to use `empty` skin, which draws nothing around or inside the box and makes its contents transparent. Another solution could change inner box margins without enlarging it. The first option produces

[image]

with following code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins, raster} 

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
number within=chapter]{EXAMPLE}[1][]{% 
breakable,
enhanced,
empty,
grow to left by=5mm,
grow to right by=5mm,
detach title,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
fontupper=\small\sffamily,
colframe=red,
colback=white,
coltitle=black,
%show bounding box,
title={EXAM},
#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Some text to show the margins. Some text to show the margins. Some text to show the margins.  

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster valign=top]
\begin{EXAMPLE}[unbreakable]{Some Title}
tcolorbox requires for a box to be rasterized that it be unbreakable. 
\end{EXAMPLE}
\begin{EXAMPLE}[unbreakable]{Some Title}
This is my own box.
\end{EXAMPLE}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

*Update:*

For boxes being as much wide as possible, it's better to use `size=minimal` (page 43) which builds boxes without padding or rules. `EXAMPLE` box could be declared like:

```
 \newtcolorbox[auto counter,
number within=chapter]{EXAMPLE}[1][]{% 
breakable,
enhanced,
size=minimal,
detach title,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
fontupper=\small\sffamily,
colframe=red,
colback=white,
coltitle=black,
show bounding box,
title={EXAM},
#1}
```

[image]

Comment: Without `grow ...` the overlap is indeed gone but I need the text in the two boxes to be as wide as possible. So, how do I reduce the left and right margins _inside_ the boxes? (But the show bounding box is very useful.)

Comment: As a hack, `left=-1mm,right=-1mm,` seems to do it.

Comment: @schremmer: Updated answer with `size=minimal` option. I think it's better than tweaking with margins.

Comment: I knew mine was only a hack. It worked but this _is_ just right. Thanks. So, now all is welll and I can return to ... writing,